# Can't authenticate after changing username to email. Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

The problem is in the title.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final SuccessUserHandler successUserHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, SuccessUserHandler successUserHandler) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.successUserHandler = successUserHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                    http    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/registration", "/error").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                            )
                            .formLogin((login) -> login
                                    .loginPage("/auth/login")
                                    .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                                    .usernameParameter("email")
                                            .successHandler(successUserHandler)
                                            .failureUrl("/auth/login?error")
                            )
                            .logout(logout -> logout
                                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
                                    .permitAll()
                            );
            return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/resouces/**","/static/**","/css/**");
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "role_id"}))
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "birthYear")
    private int birthYear;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User(String name, String surname, int birthYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", birthYear=" + birthYear +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UserDetails**

```
package task312.demo.securities;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import task312.demo.models.User;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(user.get());
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        Optional<User> foundUser = userRepository.findById(id);

        return foundUser.orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Long id, User updatedUser) {
        updatedUser.setId(id);
        userRepository.save(updatedUser);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long id) {
        Optional<User> userToDelete = userRepository.findById(id);

        //        userToDelete.ifPresent(user -> user.getRoles().clear());

        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return user.get();
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return user.get();
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isUserAdmin(String username) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
           return user.get().getRoles().stream().anyMatch(role -> "ROLE_ADMIN".equals(role.getName()));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and **SuccessHandler**

```
@Component
public class SuccessUserHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/admin");
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/user");
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 versions of this project - with username auth and email auth. Username one works fine.
The version with username auth - https://github.com/avevivi/task3.1.2

All I've changed:

1. Added .usernameParameter("email") to **SecurityConfig**;
2. Changed findByUsername() to findByEmail() in **UserRepository**;
3. Changed .getName() to .getEmail() in getUsername() of **CustomUserDetails**;
4. Changed .findByName() to .findByEmail() in loadUserByUsername() of **CustomUserDetailsService**.

Also I think maybe problem in login page or controllers since I remade it on bootstrap:

**Login page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/login.css}"/>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

<div class="container">
    <div class="justify-content-center">

            <div class="info">
                <h3>Please sign in</h3>
            </div>
            <form th:action="@{/process_login}" method="post">
                <div class="col-3 mx-auto ">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 text-center">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="text-center mt-3" style="color: red">Wrong username or password</div>

            <div class="col-3 mx-auto text-center mt-3">
            <a th:href="@{/auth/registration}" class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0">Registration</a>
            <div/>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**AuthController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(RegistrationService registrationService) {
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "auth/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String getRegistrationPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return "auth/registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String doRegistration(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        try {
            registrationService.register(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "auth/registration";
        }

        return "redirect:/auth/login";
    }
}
```

The structure looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeO7F.png)

Thank to everyone who'll help!

Comment: Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Comment: Do you mean full DEBUG log? Or what happens on sign in click?

If it's second then it generates hibernate sql queries:

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.birth_year,u1_0.email,u1_0.name,u1_0.password,u1_0.surname from user u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.name from users_roles r1_0 join role r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.birth_year,u1_0.email,u1_0.name,u1_0.password,u1_0.surname from user u1_0 where u1_0.name=?
```
But it seems like Spring can't retrieve or find user by email or smth like that

Comment: Please do not post code in comments as you can see it is completely unreadable. Use the `edit` button on your question, and yes please include debug logs _including_ context so we can see all events that lead up to your error/problem

Comment: Got it! Btw, solution is found

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem is removing wrapper class called "CustomUserDetails" in this project.

I'm not sure how Spring Security works underlying with authentication logic but it seems that the problems appear when I use wrapper class, not direct model User implements UserDetails.

So just removing "CustomUserDetails" and implementing UserDetails directly in model "User" helps here.